# change class_name of different element when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I m working on change theme in settings page, so i wanted to change the **class_name** of body when a particular radio button is **checked**

Assume the following:

```
<body class="white">

  ...

   <h4>Change Theme</h4><br>
   <input class="white" type="radio" name="white" value="white" checked >
     <label>Red</label><br>

   <input class="red" type="radio" name="red" value="red">
     <label>Red</label><br>

    <input class="black" type="radio" name="black" value="black">
     <label>Dark</label><br>


</body>
```

now i wanted to change the **class_name** of body tag as i choose from radio button

Comment: You can add a `onchange` event listener to update the `body` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `onchange` function to your radio buttons and have it set `body`'s className based on it's value like this:

```js
function handleChange(e) {
  if (e.checked)
    document.querySelector('body').className = e.value;
}
```

```css
.white {
  background: white;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<body class="white">

  <h4>Change Theme</h4><br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="white" onchange="handleChange(this)">
  <label>White</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" onchange="handleChange(this)">
  <label>Red</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="color" value="black" onchange="handleChange(this)">
  <label>Dark</label><br>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need change class_name there's a better approach to this specific problem, every `radio button` or `checkbox` have a pseudo class `:checked` which applies style when the input is in checked state, so in your css you can apply that pseudo class to your radio buttons and change the styles of whichever element you want to change.

Comment: I guess it is used to change some other styles related to the page too ! Its a radio button to change Theme, I guess he is changing the whole theme according to the radio button checked, So he may actually need to add class to body to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

set the same name for all radio buttons and I'm sharing code you can do it like that.

[Click Here](https://codepen.io/muditkashyap/pen/BajyRzY)

```js
function replaceid(color_value){

  $("#body").attr('class', color_value);
 }
```

```css
.white{
  background:#fff;
 }
 .red{
  background:red;
 }
 .black{
  background: #000;
  color:white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="white" id="body">

  ...

   <h4>Change Theme</h4><br>
   <input class="white" type="radio" name="color" value="white" checked onclick="replaceid('white')">
     <label>Red</label><br>

   <input class="red" type="radio" name="color" value="red" onclick="replaceid('red')">
     <label>Red</label><br>

    <input class="black" type="radio" name="color" value="black" onclick="replaceid('black')">
     <label>Dark</label><br>


</body>
```